# What's this class of algorithms called: (entire training dataset, new input) -> output?

Tags: machine-learning, references, algorithms, train

Supervised machine learning algorithms normally work by preprocessing a training dataset and outputting a compact model (e.g. a bunch of regression coefficients) that can quickly give an approximate answer for a new input. At that point, the original dataset can be discarded - the model serves as a proxy for it.

I'm curious about what are algorithms called that also give approximate answers for new inputs, but **have access to the entire training dataset on each query**? E.g. one obvious algorithm in this class is *nearest neighbor search*: scan the training dataset, find the most similar point(s) to the query, return (a weighted average of) their outputs.

I'm not so much concerned about the complexity, I just want to know about this problem space from a theoretical standpoint:

- What is this class of algorithms called?
- What are some other interesting algorithms in this family?
- Can they be better in quality (even if much slower) than traditional machine learning models?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, this is called [Instance-based Learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instance-based_learning), and of course other algorithms in this family are kernel methods.